# KEYSTORE.JKS exists FAILED - exited with code 1 #662 - Confluent kafka

Tags: docker, ssl, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, jks

I am trying to configure ssl to confluent kafka docker platform and getting an error while starting saying

Logs:

Command [/usr/local/bin/dub path /etc/kafka/secrets/kafka.server.keystore.jks exists] FAILED !
kafka_kafka-broker1_1_13d7835ad32d exited with code 1

Docker configuration:

```
version:  '3'
services:
  zookeeper1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.1.0
    hostname: zookeeper1
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
      - "2888:2888"
      - "3888:3888"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS:  0.0.0.0:2888:3888
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    logging:  
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "3"
    volumes:
      - zookeeper-data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - zookeeper-log:/var/lib/zookeeper/log
  kafka-broker1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.1.0
    hostname: kafka-broker1:
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9093:9093"
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: "PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092,SSL://0.0.0.0:9093"
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: "PLAINTEXT://kafkassl.com:9092,SSL://kafkassl.com:9093"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper1:2181
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "kafka.controller=INFO,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=INFO,state.change.logger=INFO"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "false"
      KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE: "true"
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_HOURS: 168
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_RETENTION_MINUTES: 43800
      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_FILENAME: kafka.server.keystore.jks
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION: /ssl/kafka.server.truststore.jks
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD: pass
      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION: /ssl/kafka.server.keystore.jks
      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD: pass
      KAFKA_SSL_KEY_PASSWORD: pass
    volumes:
      - kafka-data:/var/lib/kafka/data
      - /ssl:/etc/kafka/secrets

    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "3"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper1
volumes:
  zookeeper-data:
  zookeeper-log:
  kafka-data:
```

Comment: Please show your docker configuration

Comment: Added the docker  configuration above please check. Thanks a lot

Comment: Your volume is at `/etc/kafka/sercrets`, so the environment variables need to use `/etc/kafka/secrets/` as well.  I strongly suggest [starting with the example](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/tree/5.1.0-post/examples/kafka-cluster-ssl), then only editing the JKS files and passwords, and leave the Docker Compose file alone.

Comment: I have found the solution.
Steps:
1. Create a folder and copy you .jks files
2. create three text files and paste you password for the jks
3. And mount the jks and text files which contains the password. This will definitely work.

Example:

the below environment properties should be a text file for your kafka in docker compose file

      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_CREDENTIALS: keystore_creds   --> <text file contains the jks password>

Comment: Feel free to post your answer below rather than as a comment

Comment: @Senthil, could you please add an answer to this question, with the final look of the docker-compose?

Answer (score 1):

Below are the steps that one can use to start the kafka docker-compose with the SSL support (@Senthil already provided some guidance in his comments)

- in the docker-compose directory there is a so called secrets directory which contains the shell script for generating the keystore, truststore and ssl passwords. Go into the root of the docker-compose for kafka and run this script that will generate the needed files (eg: `./secrets/create-certs` )
- copy all the generated files into the secrets directory
- mount the volume of the secrets directory from the host machine to the dockerized one. put the following on the docker-compose file at the volumes sections

> ```
> volumes:
>   - ./secrets/:/etc/kafka/secrets
> ```

Run with docker-compose up

Answer (score 1):

These steps worked for me in Windows:

1 - Generate keys using Windows WSL:

`cd $(pwd)/examples/kafka-cluster-ssl/secrets`
`./create-certs.sh`
`(Type yes for all "Trust this certificate? [no]:" prompts.)`

2 - Set the environment variable **KAFKA_SSL_SECRETS_DIR** using **PowerShell**:

`$env:KAFKA_SSL_SECRETS_DIR= "xxxx\cp-docker-images\examples\kafka-cluster-ssl\secrets"`

3 - Use the environment variable to run kafka-ssl cluster node:

`docker run -d --net=host --name=kafka-ssl-1    -e` 
`KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=localhost:22181,localhost:32181,localhost:42181    -e` 
`KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=SSL://localhost:29092    -e KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_FILENAME=kafka.broker1.keystore.jks    -e` 
`KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_CREDENTIALS=broker1_keystore_creds    -e KAFKA_SSL_KEY_CREDENTIALS=broker1_sslkey_creds    -e` 
`KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_FILENAME=kafka.broker1.truststore.jks    -e` 
`KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_CREDENTIALS=broker1_truststore_creds    -e KAFKA_SECURITY_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL=SSL    -v` 
`${env:KAFKA_SSL_SECRETS_DIR}:/etc/kafka/secrets    confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, here is what I used to resolve this and what issues I have run into with it.  Here is part of my docker compose file.  If you were to open the file kafka_Secret.txt, you would see only **P@ssword** in it.  A problem I want into is that - ./kafka/secrets:/etc/kafka/secrets was set up as a volume instead of a bind mount.  I confirmed this by running container inspect .  (Get the container name by running docker container ls).  It showed a volume mount instead of a bind mount.  To fix it, I deleted the volumes from my docker to start over.  The volume that hung around kept attaching to my kafka container even if I recreated the container.

```
  zookeeper:
image: zookeeper:3.4.9
hostname: zookeeper
ports:
  - '2181:2181'
environment:
  ZOO_MY_ID: 1
  ZOO_PORT: 2181
  ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zookeeper:2888:3888
  ZOO_LOG4J_PROP: "${KAFKA_LOG_LEVEL},CONSOLE"
networks:
  - ms_network
volumes:
  - ./kafka/zookeeper/data:/data
  - ./kafka/zookeeper/datalog:/datalog


kafka:
image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.5.0
hostname: kafka
ports:
  - '19092:19092'
environment:
  KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
  KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: SSL://kafka:19092
  KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_FILENAME: keystore.jks
  KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_CREDENTIALS: kafka_secret.txt
  KAFKA_SSL_KEY_CREDENTIALS: kafka_secret.txt
  KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_FILENAME: truststore.jks
  KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_CREDENTIALS: kafka_secret.txt
  KAFKA_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: " "
  KAFKA_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH: requested
  KAFKA_SECURITY_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL: SSL
  KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: 'org.apache.zookeeper=${KAFKA_LOG_LEVEL},org.apache.kafka=${KAFKA_LOG_LEVEL},kafka=${KAFKA_LOG_LEVEL},kafka.cluster=${KAFKA_LOG_LEVEL},kafka.controller=${KAFKA_LOG_LEVEL},kafka.coordinator=${KAFKA_LOG_LEVEL},kafka.log=${KAFKA_LOG_LEVEL},kafka.server=${KAFKA_LOG_LEVEL},kafka.zookeeper=${KAFKA_LOG_LEVEL},state.change.logger=${KAFKA_LOG_LEVEL},kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=${KAFKA_LOG_LEVEL},kafka.authorizer.logger=${KAFKA_LOG_LEVEL},kafka.log.LogCleaner=${KAFKA_LOG_LEVEL},kafka.request.logger=${KAFKA_LOG_LEVEL}'
  KAFKA_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: ${KAFKA_LOG_LEVEL}
  KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
volumes:
  - ./kafka/secrets:/etc/kafka/secrets
  - ./kafka/data:/var/lib/kafka/data
depends_on:
  - zookeeper
networks:
  - ms_network
```